# Chrome Extension + Rails Doorkeeper, anyone knows what should be the callback on the extension?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome-extension, oauth, doorkeeper

I'm using Doorkeeper for my Rails provider.
My Chrome extension should implement Oauth to my provider.
When I generate a new application in the provider I need to give the callback URL, what is the Chrome extension URL for that callback?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [chrome.identity API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity) wherein `getRedirectURL` method generates a redirect URL to be used in `launchWebAuthFlow` method.

The generated URLs match the pattern `https://<app-id>.chromiumapp.org/*`.

This [thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/wKNy65FqJSY) might also help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.